# Wiremock dynamic response based on request - jsonPath is not working

Tags: jsonpath, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I'm using Wiremock standalone and below are sample of request/response. jsonPath is not working and it's returing the whole code. What am I doing wrong?

Sample Request

```
{
    "source": "Web",
    "orders":[ 
        {
            "id": "Order1",
            "status": "In Progress"
        },
        {
            "id": "Order2",            
            "status": "In Progress"
        }
    ]    
}
```

Expected Response

```
{
    "user": "User1",
    "orders": [
        {
            "id": "Order1",
            "status": "In Progress", 
            "shipping": "Pending"
        },
        {
            "id": "Order2",            
            "status": "In Progress",
            "shipping": "Pending"
        }
    ]
}
```

My response.json

```
{
    "user": "User1",
    "orders": [
          {{#each (jsonPath request.body '$.batches') as |batches|}}
          {
             "id": "{{{batches.id}}}",
             "status": "In Progress", 
             "shipping": "Pending"
          }{{^last}},{{/last}}
          {{//each}}
    ]
}
```

Actual Response

```
{
    "user": "User1",
    "orders": [
          {{#each (jsonPath request.body '$.batches') as |batches|}}
          {
             "id": "{{{batches.id}}}",
             "status": "In Progress", 
             "shipping": "Pending"
          }{{^last}},{{/last}}
          {{//each}}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of WireMock?

Comment: @Tom, yes. I download the latest version from the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when nothing is parsed it means response-templating isn't enabled for this response.  To enable response-templating you can add it to the stub mapping by adding the `transformers` field:

```json
  "name" : "orders",
  "request" : {
    "url" : "/orders",
    "method" : "GET"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName": "response.json",
    "transformers": [
      "response-template"
    ],
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }
}
```

With the above stub mapping and this `response.json` file:

```
{
  "user": "User1", 
  "orders": [ 
    {{#each (jsonPath request.body '$.orders') as |order|}} 
      {
        "id": "{{order.id}}", 
        "status": "In Progress", 
        "shipping": "Pending"
      } {{#not @last}},{{/not}}  
    {{/each}} 
  ]
}
```

I was able to produce the output you are looking for.  This request:

```json
{
  "source": "Web",
  "orders": [
    {
      "id": "Order1",
      "status": "In Progress"
    },
    {
      "id": "Order2",
      "status": "In Progress"
    },
    {
      "id": "Order3",
      "status": "In Progress"
    }
  ]
}
```

Produces this output from wiremock:

```json
{
  "user": "User1",
  "orders": [
    {
      "id": "Order1",
      "status": "In Progress",
      "shipping": "Pending"
    },
    {
      "id": "Order2",
      "status": "In Progress",
      "shipping": "Pending"
    },
    {
      "id": "Order3",
      "status": "In Progress",
      "shipping": "Pending"
    }
  ]
}
```

The `jsonPath` matches on the array in the request and the `each` loops through those elements.  The `not` checks to see if it is the last element in the loop and if not, add the `,` to make the response valid json.

There is a great explanation of the conditional logic and iteration here - https://docs.wiremock.io/response-templating/conditional-logic-and-iteration/

This was all done using the latest version of wiremock - currently 3.2.0

Comment: Thanks Lee! Appreciate your help! It's working now :)